# Joomla! fails to load CSS files when running on Firefox with SSL

Tags: templates, css, ssl

The easiest way to see my problem is to check this site with SSL:
https://www.rekuperatory.pl/zapytanie-ofertowe
on two browsers, one being Firefox.

The thing is, it loads correctly in Chrome, IE, Opera, but in Firefox it fails to load CSS files. There's no issue when visiting the site via HTTP:
http://www.rekuperatory.pl/zapytanie-ofertowe - it loads just fine on every browser including Firefox. The problem is only with Firefox, only via HTTPS.

When I contacted hosting provider, they assured me, that everything is all right with SSL Certificate and the problem must be in linking files. But I don't see how may I change this. My stylesheet files are added like that:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();    
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/default.css');
```

The funny thing is that when I run JCH Optimize, CSS files from template start working, but unfortunatelly the ones from custom modules don't. In modules there is slighly different way of adding CSS files. For example:

```
$doc->addStyleSheet( JURI::root(true) . '/modules/mod_mapa/css/style.css' );
```

I'm using Joomla! 3.4 but the problem was first seen on 3.2

Comment: What happens if you disable SEF URL's ?

Comment: Have you also tried following the instructions given in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986572/ssl-issue-in-joomla-web-site

Comment: Disabling SEF URLs doesn't change a thing. Enforcing SSL frm admin panel also doesn't help.

Comment: Hmm odd. I remember there being a bug in Firefox with SSL and assets being loaded. Are you sure you're using the latest version of Firefox?

Comment: i m checking your site for some time now, it's really weird. The css is not missing when on SSL, but FF won't load it, nor it will throw any warning. I would try to eliminate causes one by one. It would be interesting to see if the same happens at a different host.

Comment: Yeah, that's really strange. Firefox version doesn't matter - problem occurs also on the Developer Edition (v38). Trying on different host is kind of problematic since it would require to move domain and SSL certificate (which I cannot do), or buying a new certificate. I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: Did you fix your problem? The website looks the same to me on Chrome and Firefox (36.0.1) using HTTPS

Comment: Can confirm it must be fixed now >> Firefox Beta 37. Please could you write an answer explaining how you got it working?

Comment: Turns out, it wasn't Joomla's fault. I've recreated an issue with static HTML file. Fortunately, I've found a cause - .htaccess entry responsible for browser cache. You can find more on the topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003838/firefox-fails-to-load-css-files-on-https/